# Rename estimation result scalars

Tags: stata

After running a regression using the `prais` command, I have the following estimation results:

```
. ereturn list

scalars:
               e(rank) =  6
                e(rho) =  .6151469935838732
               e(dw_0) =  .9120035305269839
... etc
```

I want to display `e(dw_0)` using `esttab` so I do:

```
.  esttab myregression,label scalars(dw_0)
```

This displays the number, but keeps the rather unhelpful `dw_0` label.

How can I rename this so it reports, for example, `Durbin-Watson statistic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`esttab` is a wrapper for `estout` with the most common options. Please check out the `stats()` option to `estout`. `stats()` has a suboption to allow formats and labels (and probably a few other things). You can mix `esttab` and `estout` options.

I find `estout` does just about everything you could possibly want.

```
sysuse auto, clear
generate time = _n
tsset time

eststo clear
prais price weight
eststo

esttab, label stats(dw_0, fmt(%9.3f) labels(Durbin-Watson))


. esttab, label stats(dw_0, fmt(%9.3f) labels(Durbin-Watson))

------------------------------------
                              (1)   
                            Price   
------------------------------------
Weight (lbs.)               2.778***
                           (7.73)   

Constant                  -2170.2   
                          (-1.80)   
------------------------------------
Durbin-Watson               1.105   
------------------------------------
t statistics in parentheses
* p<0.05, ** p<0.01, *** p<0.001
```

Comment: Yes, this is incredibly useful. I didn't know you could use `esttab` options in `estout`. Very nice indeed.

Comment: Seems like @NickCox and a few other users are doing the leg work of answering Stata questions here. Help us get the Stata documentation off the ground, by voting for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/stata/commit).

Comment: @LondonRob committed. I read the docs, but don't understand why it is different/better than Q&A format. Maybe they just want us to spend more time on SO? :)